# How to Replace a value in SQL only to a certain extent

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have this column 'image' in my table 'details'

values of image is in this syntax

`onlinefolder1/onlinefolder2/../someid.png`

I downloaded all the images from these url to a local folder in my website

`localfolder1/localfolder2/../someid.png`

Now I wish to **UPDATE** the url in the database to the url that points to my local folder.

I know I can achieve this using PHP.

**Question:** Just curious whether I can update my column with SQL alone(since reading every url from the database and replacing it didn't seem quite good).

I wish to REPLACE `onlinefolder1/onlinefolder2/../` with `localfolder1/localfolder2/../`.

**note:** `someid` is unique. Am using `mysql` database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
UPDATE details 
SET image = REPLACE(image, 'online1/online2/', 'local1/local2/')
WHERE image LIKE 'online1/online2/%';
```

NOTE: Values have been shortened.